# Filter array of date strings using array_filter

Tags: php, arrays, date, filter

I have an array of date strings:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2014-03-24
    [1] => 2014-03-18
    [2] => 2014-06-08
    [3] => 2014-08-21
    [4] => 2014-09-11
)
```

I'd like to use the array_filter function to filter out all the entries older than a specific month and year:

```
array_filter($array, "newer_than");

function newer_than($var)
{
    return (strtotime($var) > CURRENT MONTH AND YEAR);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You want to filter out entries before the current time? Use `time()` in place of `CURRENT MONTH AND YEAR`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strtotime()` is smart enough to get the UNIX timestamp of the current month:

```
$thisMonth = strtotime('first day of ' . date('F Y'));

$array2 = array_filter($array1, function ($val) use ($thisMonth) {
    return strtotime($val) > $thisMonth;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify a month and year that are not the current ones, you can do something like this:

```
    <?
    $array[] = "2014-03-24";
    $array[] = "2014-03-18";
    $array[] = "2014-06-08";
    $array[] = "2014-08-21";
    $array[] = "2014-09-11";

    $array = array_filter($array, "newer_than");

    function newer_than($var)
    {
            $specificMonth = 8;
            $specificYear = 2014;

            return (strtotime($var) > mktime(0,0,0,$specificMonth,1,$specificYear) );
    }

    ?>
```